# Find all real $c \neq 0$ and all nonzero $f$ in $V$ such that $T(f)=cf$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

The question states:

> Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be the linear transformation defined as follows: If $f\in V, g=T(f)$means that $$g(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\{1+\cos(x-t)\}f(t)~dt$$
>   Find all real $c \neq 0$ and all nonzero $f$ in $V$ such that $T(f)=cf$.

Now $f$ must be in $T(V)$ (the range of $T$ if $T(f)=cf$. And a basis for $T$ is $\{1,\cos x, \sin x\}$.

I suppose that the above information should help me solve the problem... Must $f$ thus be a linear combination of the elements of the basis? And if so, how do I find the $c$? Isn't it all $c\in \mathbb R$?

**Edit:**$~V$ denotes the linear space of all real functions continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: What is $V$? Seems to be some space of functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ but it's not clear what functions are in the space. All continuous such? or which?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I edited explaining that. $V$ is the linear space of all real functions continuous on $[-\pi, pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
T(f)(x) &=
\int_{-\pi}^\pi(1+\cos(x-t))f(t)dt
\\&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi(1+\cos x\cos t+\sin x\sin t)f(t)dt
\\ &=
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt+\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos tf(t)dt\right)\cos x+\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin tf(t)dt\right)\sin x
\end{align}

Note that $T(f)=cf$ means $T(f)(x)=cf(x)$ $\forall x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ , and hence $\forall x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ we have
$$f(x)=c_1+c_2\cos x+c_3\sin x  $$

$$
T(f)(x)= 2\pi c_1 + c_2 \pi \cos x + c_3 \pi \sin x 
$$

Thus the solution is $f=a\cos x+ b \sin x$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a^2+b^2\ne0$ and $c=\pi$ or $f \equiv 1$ and $c=2\pi$.

Comment: I think  you have missed one solution. $c=2\pi$ and $f \equiv 1$ is also a solution.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for reminding me of that!