# why $2\pi= c$ and $c=\pi ?$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be the linear transformation defined as follows: If $f\in V, g=T(f)$means that $$g(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\{1+\cos(x-t)\}f(t)~dt$$
> Find all real $c \neq 0$ and all nonzero $f$ in $V$ such that $T(f)=cf$.

My attempt : I got the answer but i didn't understand the answer given below marked in red box

[image]

My thinking : $$f(x)=c_1+c_2\cos x+c_3\sin x  $$

$$T(f)(x)= cf(x)$$
$$
T(f)(x)= c c_1 + c c_2 \cos x + c c_3  \sin x 
$$

I m not getting  how $\pi$ come in the given  answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290699/557708 ?

why $2\pi= c$ and  $c=\pi ?$

Comment: Did you calculate those integrals for this particular input $f$? In other words, did you work out the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the basis $\{1,\cos x,\sin x\}$?

Comment: okks @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you know the general form of $f(x) = c_1 + c_2\cos x + c_3\sin x$, you can find the coefficients in terms of the integral

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)dt = 2\pi c_1$$
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos t(c_1 + c_2\cos t + c_3\sin t)dt = c_2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2 tdt = \pi c_2$$
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin t(c_1 + c_2\cos t + c_3\sin t)dt = c_3\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2 tdt = \pi c_3$$

So we can write the following

$$T(c_1 + c_2\cos x + c_3\sin x) = 2\pi c_1 + \pi c_2 \cos x + \pi c_3 \sin x = cc_1 + cc_2\cos x + cc_3\sin x$$